# Importing my own classes when compiling and running Java file on Windows powershell

Tags: java, powershell, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on a Java project where there is a directory `Project` which has two sub-directories(`GUI` and `Logic`)

### Relevant classes:

- frame.java(`GUI` package)
- logic.java(`Logic` package)

The main class is in the `GUI` package and it imports a file which is in the 'Logic' package.

On trying the below command and running the file, I encounter an `NoClassDefFoundError'.

```
javac -sourcepath [path to Project] [file containing the import]
```

Comment: What are the Java packages the files are belonging to?

Comment: I edited my post. There're two files, one in gui package and the other one in logic package.

Comment: Make jar of logic package. while running class in the gui package , add that in the classpath

Comment: Kalaiarasan Manimaran, how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could compile it. All the directories and package names were, right, what I needed to do was to use the following command from my root directory:

```
javac src/gui/*.java
```

and then, to run:

```
 java -cp ./src gui.Gui
```

Thanks for the ones who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand your directory structure is like

```
.\source
.\source\GUI
.\source\GUI\frame.java
.\source\Logic
.\source\Logic\logic.java
```

Then this will not work, as the direcotry names should be named like the package names. Change the structure and the class names as

```
.\source\gui
.\source\gui\Frame.java
.\source\logic
.\source\logic\Logic.java
```

Assuming the import statements and the class names inside the file are correctly amended you can compile it with

```
javac -sourcepath source source\gui\Frame.java
```

Comment: The package name in the .java is the exact name of the directory name. I tried to use sourcepath like you said, however I still get the NoClassDefFoundError when I try to run the .class.

Comment: I could notice that the problem isn't exactly with the import right now, since I commented it and I still get the problem. The error happens when I specify the sourcepath. If I comment the import and compile it like   " javac gui.java "   it works, however I can't do it.